# VS2010 Evaluation Crashing while Creating new Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I thought of Trying new VS 2010 Professional. So I have installed an evaluation copy. But when I am clicking on New Project-> and trying to edit the Default project name to some other name in the new project Window, It's crashing my VS2010. Any Idea what I need to do? Does anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks in Advance
**Chetan**

Comment: No. It's just directly taking me to Send report page. And it's frustating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this... I remember The 2 days back when I have installed VS2010(Evaluation), that time I was able to create a simple Hello World application in that. and It was working fine that time. And I remember installing MS Enterprise Library 4.1 after that for some of my diff project. And now I Uninstalled MS Enterprise Library and It' started working fine again. I don't know the relation though. But yeah It's working.

Thanks for your time guys. You guys are always helpful though.

Regards,

**Chetan**